# Is it possible to link axes from different plots in pandas-bokeh package?

Tags: python, plot, linker, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

In regular Bokeh there is a nice feature of linking axes from different subplots in a grid which e.g. is very useful for zooming on multiple graphs simultaneously. But this doesn't seem to work in the pandas-bokeh package - any good solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

It is not streight forward, but you can make use of `js_link` of the [`x_range`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html?highlight=x_range#bokeh.models.Plot.x_range) and this is not too complicated. The same of course for the `y_range` if wanted.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh as pdb
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook
output_notebook()

# data
data = list(range(5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':data, 'y':data[::-1]})

# plots
p1 = pdb.plot(df['x'], show_figure=False)
p2 = pdb.plot(df['y'], show_figure=False)

# linking p1 ranges to p2
p1.x_range.js_link('start', p2.x_range, 'start')
p1.x_range.js_link('end', p2.x_range, 'end')
p1.y_range.js_link('start', p2.y_range, 'start')
p1.y_range.js_link('end', p2.y_range, 'end')

# linking p2 ranges to p1 vice versa
p2.x_range.js_link('start', p1.x_range, 'start')
p2.x_range.js_link('end', p1.x_range, 'end')
p2.y_range.js_link('start', p1.y_range, 'start')
p2.y_range.js_link('end', p1.y_range, 'end')

pdb.plot_grid([[p1],[p2]])
```

**Comment**

In an ideal world

```
p1 = pdb.plot(df['x'], show_figure=False)
p2 = pdb.plot(df['y'], x_arnge=p1.x_range, y_range=p1.y_range, show_figure=False)
pdb.plot_grid([[p1],[p2]])
```

should work. This is not, because in [pandas-bokeh.plot()](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh/blob/e71bb528e001d3e32214069b8489083e29daf419/pandas_bokeh/plot.py#L249) not all keyword arguments of the `figure` object are evaluated. In my opinion this is a misconfiguration and I opend a ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh/issues/126) to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. And yes, I agree with your final comments. This was indeed what I hope to transfer from classical bokeh to pandas_bokeh.